# jquery chaining function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote this function to toggle a class name, of next div using jquery chaining function, but it doen't work...

```
  $('a.back-btn,a.front-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('back-btn front-btn').end()
        .next().find('.models').toggleClass('rotated');
})
```

in case if i write separate line, then it works fine :

```
$('a.back-btn,a.front-btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('back-btn front-btn');
            $(this).next('.models').toggleClass('rotated'); // separate line
        })
```

what is the issue with my chaining function, how it need to end a process in case if i use the chaining. i used end(), is it wrong? any best clarification to use end()?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your two pieces of code aren't equivalent. `$(this).next('.models')` returns the element after `this` if it has the class `models`. `$(this).next().find('.models')` returns all elements that have the class `models` and are descendents of the element after `this`. Honestly, I'm not entirely convinced that the `.end()` was the only issue, and rather you were writing code that wasn't what you actually meant or wanted.

Comment: Reading the [jQuery doc for `.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) should clear things up.  The `.end()` is not needed and is messing things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `end()` function ends a child selection.
You shouldn't use it here.

`end()` would be used like this:

```
$(something)
    .children()
        .hide()
    .end()    //Go back to the original something
    .animate()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you remove `end()`, it'll work. Using `end()` only applies when you have ran a function in the current jQuery chain which altered the set you were working on.

```
$('a.back-btn,a.front-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('back-btn front-btn').next('.models').toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

Here's a valid (but completely pointless) use of `end()`:

```
$(this).next('.models').toggleClass('rotated').end().toggleClass('back-btn front-btn');
```

The `next()` method alters the current *set* of jQuery elements we're working on, so the `toggleClass` method works on the next `.models` element. We then `end()` to return to `$(this)`, on which we toggle the `rotated` class.

See the [`end()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/end) for another explanation/ example.